# Microsoft Graph API Security .net Core Client ID

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am following a tutorial from this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core?tutorial-step=3)

If you see the `DeviceCodeAuthProvider` and `GetAccessToken`, you would be able to get the token merely just by the app Id and the scope without any app/ client secret or password. You can also refresh the token just by providing the same info. My question is, is this safe? I thought the client id is just like a username.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code). The DeviceCodeflow will provide the device code to validate the user/client id/app id and that is safe.

Device code flow protocol:
[image: Device code flow protocol]